# I'm studying about differential cryptanalysis in DES. I need to make the DDT through python

Tags: cryptanalysis, des

I just made DES algorithm(encryption, decryption) using python.
And I want to attack 1,2 4,8 .. round DES.
For that, I need to make the DDT code.
Could you guys help me to make the DDT?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm studying Adi Shamir's article.(Differential Cryptanalysis of the Data Encryption Standard)

Comment: We can only help you if you tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok. Honestly, I don't know where to start to make the DDT. Can you give me some clue? I'll do it.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - I recommend that you still write the code yourself, but if you want an implementation to look at, I have one [here](https://github.com/erose1337/crypto/blob/master/analysis/differential.py). (No guarantee of correctness is provided, but it might be useful as a guide). We can't give you much more help than the psuedo-code in the linked duplicate, programming questions are off-topic here.